# enable editing in Medium Editor

Tags: jquery, medium-editor

I want to use Medium Editor for inline editing. On one page it's working. However on another page I want the editor to be disabled at the beginning, as the text is normally only for reading. It's disabled with `disableEditing: true` when initializing the editor.

However I can't enable it again. I found nothing about changing the settings afterwards and whatever I tried, nothing worked.

```js
var helpeditor = new MediumEditor("#htext", {
  extensions: {
    "autolist": autolist
  },
  toolbar: {
    buttons: ["bold", "italic", "underline", "unorderedlist", "orderedlist", "justifyLeft", "justifyCenter"]
  },
  disableEditing: true
});
```

Comment: From the [documentation](https://github.com/yabwe/medium-editor/blob/master/API.md#setup) it doesn't look like that library supports changing properties after initialisation. You'd need to destroy the existing instance and create a new one which does allow editing. Alternatively, use a better library which meets all your needs.

Comment: Yes, destroying and new setting up works now. I just wonder what sense it makes to create such a behavior?? Thanks for you tip!

Comment: Glad you got it working. I added it as an answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/yabwe/medium-editor/blob/master/API.md) it doesn't look like that library supports changing properties after initialisation. You'd need to [`destroy()`](https://github.com/yabwe/medium-editor/blob/master/API.md#destroy) the existing instance and create a new one which does allow editing.

Alternatively, use a better library which meets all your needs.